# My secondary nodes data gets replaced w garbage when adding a new first node in my doubly linked list

Tags: c, linked-list, dynamic-memory-allocation, doubly-linked-list, calloc

I am working on a lab for school and we are supposed to implement functions to practice using linked list. I cant get past an assert(getFirstElement(head) == 2) because the data is just garbage (16040, 32030, you get the idea).

When I debugged, it seems like the data does get initiated correctly, only to randomly get replaced when I link the node into the list.

Here are the functions I wrote to allocate and initiate (the function heads and names are given). Everything works fine, and it does save the right data in the second node up until here ->

```
struct node
{
    Data data;
    struct node *next;
    struct node *previous;
};

typedef struct node *List;

typedef int Data;

List createEmptyList(void)
{
    return NULL;
}

static struct node* createListNode(const Data data)
{
    struct node* newNode = (struct node*)calloc(1, sizeof(struct node*));
    
    if (newNode == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error");
        return NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        newNode->data = data;
        newNode->next = NULL;
        newNode->previous = NULL;
        return newNode;
    }
}


void addFirst(List *list, const Data data)
{
    List newNode = createListNode(data);
    newNode->next = (*list);
    if (*list != NULL)
    {
        (*list)->previous = newNode;   <- After this line the second nodes data turns into garbage
    }
    (*list) = newNode;
    
    assert(*list != NULL);
}

void testFunction(List head)
{
    printf("Starting test\n");
    
    assert(isEmpty(head));

    addFirst(&head, 6);
    addFirst(&head, 5);
    addFirst(&head, 4);
    addFirst(&head, 3);
    addFirst(&head, 2);
    assert(numberOfNodesInList(head) == 5);
    assert(getFirstElement(head) == 2);
}

int main(void)
{
    List head = createEmptyList();
    
    testFunction(head);
    
    return 0;
}
```

I've added part of the code where I get stuck.

I do not understand what goes wrong, any help is appreciated!
Everything else seems to work fine.

Data is just an int, it's been typedef by my teacher

Comment: i am brand new to this, but this is part of the code where i trigger the assert, the whole thing is 2 c.files and 1 h.file so im not sure what would be helpful to know apart from what i already posted


````
void testFunction(List head)
{
    printf("Starting test\n");
    
    assert(isEmpty(head)); 
    addFirst(&head, 6);
    addFirst(&head, 5);
    addFirst(&head, 4);
    addFirst(&head, 3);
    addFirst(&head, 2);
    assert(numberOfNodesInList(head) == 5);
    assert(getFirstElement(head) == 2);
````

Comment: Hint: don't hide pointer types with typedefs like you've done with `List` it only causes confusion.

Comment: Its a skeleton given to me by the teacher, and we arent allowed to change functionheads and typedefs

Comment: Don't put code into comments, it's unreadable. Instead [edit] your question and put all clarifications _there_. Read about [mcve] and provide one. Yes, it means some work for you, but that's the price to pay if you want an answer.

Comment: OK for the typedefs, if your teacher requests it you have to cope with it.

Comment: @LinneaFries we need a [mcve] **<- read this**. A complete minimal compilable example that shows the problem along with expected output and input (if necessary).

Comment: It's still not a [mcve], your code doesn't compile. `isEmpty`, `numberOfNodesInList` and `getFirstElement` are not defined. Before posting your code check at least if it compiles. Also include the `#include`s, they really matter.

Answer (score 2):

In the function `createListNode`

```
static struct node* createListNode(const Data data)
{
    struct node* newNode = (struct node*)calloc(1, sizeof(struct node*));
    //...
```

you are allocating memory for a pointer instead of allocting memory for an object of the type `struct node`.

You need to write

```
    struct node* newNode = (struct node*)calloc(1, sizeof(struct node));
```

or

```
    struct node* newNode = (struct node*)calloc(1, sizeof( *newNode ));
```

Pay attention to that this typedef declaration

```
typedef int Data;
```

must precede the declaration of the structure `struct node`

Also in the function `addFirst`

```
void addFirst(List *list, const Data data)
{
    List newNode = createListNode(data);
    //...
```

you need to check whether `newNode` is a null pointer or not.

Comment: Or even better `struct node* newNode = calloc(1, sizeof( *newNode ))`, the cast being basically useless.